# Chrome devtools extension: Am I inspecting a chrome internal page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am writing a chrome devtools extension. When devtools is opened, I need to prompt the user; all good. The problem is when I use devtools to inspect the devtools window: there is a loop triggered.

The solution would be to disable the extension when devtools is used to inspect an internal chrome:// page. But there isn't a clear way to check for this. I suppose I could evaluate code in the inspected window to check for the URL; this seems a bit messy. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

What I wound up doing is checking the URL on navigation; the user will have to reload the page. I am open to other ideas though.

```
chrome.devtools.network.onNavigated.addListener(function(url) {

    if (url.substr(0,9) != "chrome://") {
        // Initialize
```